# WannaCry ransomware backtrace

Tags: network, legal, ransomware

Can law-enforcement agency trace the source of code, emails or bitcoins destination to catch criminals? After all, someone will get these bitcoins and someone will be using a computer to do it?

Comment: you've actually asked 3 questions: tracing source code, tracing email, and tracing bitcoin. the answer to all 3 is "maybe"

Comment: Agreed.  Maybe they can, maybe they can't.  BTC transactions all have unique identifiers.  Just imagine that every time you go to the bank to get cash, or use an ATM for same, the serial numbers for each bill is recorded.  Then when you spend that money at 7-11 it is scanned again there.  There is a clear trace between your withdrawal and your spending of that bill.  But in reality, 7-11 mixes the money in their cash drawers so your bill might go to someone else rather than to their bank account where it might be scanned.  Bitcoin "mixers" exist for just that purpose.